# ¿Cómo puedo contar las letras del alfabeto español? Incluyendo letras con tilde en C++

Tags: regex, c++11

Estoy intentando diseñar una función, usando expresiones regulares, que cuente las letras de una palabra, frase o texto en español. Debe contar las vocales con tilde y la **ñ**, siendo éstas en mayúsculas como minúsculas.

Por ejemplo:

```
cout << "Cantidad de letras: " << letters_counted( "¿Hola, cómo estás?" ) << endl;
```

El resultado debería ser:

```
Cantidad de letras: 13
```

Otros ejemplos:

- *"Ñandú"*. Debería contar 5 letras.
- *"Eres un Compañero"*. Debería contar 15 letras.
- *"Ññ óuaí"*. Debería contar 6 letras.

No estoy encontrando la forma de comparar letras con tildes, ¿hay alguna forma?

---

Este es un intento que me falló:

```
int count=0; txt="Hola, cómo estás";

regex rx( "[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]" );

for( sregex_iterator it( txt.cbegin(), txt.cend(), rx ); it!=sregex_iterator();
  ++it ) count++;
cout << count << endl;
```

En vez de mostrar 13, que es la cantidad de letras que hay, me devuelve 15.

No entiendo cómo tratar a los caracteres extendidos, como las vocales con tilde, **á, é, í, ó, ú** y la **ñ**.

---

Este es otro intento, el algoritmo es similar al de @AngelAngel.

```
int letters_counted_in_text( std::string const&text ) {
  count = 0
  string abc = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzáéíóú"
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ";
  for( unsigned i=0; i<text.length(); ++i )
    for( unsigned j=0; j<abc.length(); ++j )
      if( text.at( i )==abc.at( j ) )
      {
        count++;
        j=abc.length();
      }
  return count;
}
```

Pero también me retorna 15 letras cuando debería ser 13, al ejemplo "**Hola, cómo estás**".

¿Hay posibilidad de usar u16string o wstring? Para tratar las letras del alfabeto español.

Comment: creo que entiendo su pregunta hasta aqui -> *No estoy encontrando la forma de comparar letras con tildes, ¿hay alguna forma?* no ser si eso era para otra pregunta puede aclararlo de no se asi, yo entiendo hasta esa parte que quiere contar cuantos caracteres existen, pero despues leo lo otro. Saludos

Comment: Emanuel, si deseas actualizar tu pregunta, **[sigue este enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55302/78)**. He editado tu pregunta agregando esta información.

Comment: Gracias por el arreglo @MauricioAriasOlave . Soy nuevo en stackoverflow, y me estoy adaptando a la interfaz de esta plataforma.

Comment: @EmanuelGauler, con todo gusto. No hay problema. Todos aprendemos. Saludos.

Comment: Relacionada: http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56038/19610

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*he visto que modifico su pregunta borrare mi respuesta anterior, dejare algunas aclaraciones sobre porque esos codigos funcionaban*

---

Bien al lio que seguro tiene prisa.

De su pregunta:

> Este es un intento que me falló:
>
> ```
> int count=0; txt="Hola, cómo estás";
> regex rx( "[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]" );
> for( sregex_iterator it( txt.cbegin(), txt.cend(), rx ); it!=sregex_iterator();
>   ++it ) count++;
> cout << count << endl;
> ```
>
> En vez de mostrar 13, que es la cantidad de letras que hay, me
>   devuelve 15.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int count=0; 

    wstring txt = L"Hola, cómo estás";

wregex rx( L"[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]" );

for( wsregex_iterator it( txt.cbegin(), txt.cend(), rx ); it!=wsregex_iterator();
  ++it ) count++;
cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[testideone](https://ideone.com/EaYxxS)</kbd>

**cambios:**

- `string` por [`wstring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/) y añadimos `L`:

  `wstring txt = L"Hola, cómo estás";`
- `regex` por [`wregex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/wregex/) y añadimos `L`:

  `wregex rx( L"[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]" );`
- `sregex_iterator` por `wsregex_iterator`

  `for( wsregex_iterator...`
- `sregex_iterator();` por `wsregex_iterator();`

  `it!=wsregex_iterator();`

---

De su pregunta:

> Este es otro intento, el algoritmo es similar al de @AngelAngel.
>
> ```
> int letters_counted_in_text( std::string const&text ) {
>   count = 0
>   string abc = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzáéíóú"
>       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ";
>   for( unsigned i=0; i<text.length(); ++i )
>     for( unsigned j=0; j<abc.length(); ++j )
>       if( text.at( i )==abc.at( j ) )
>       {
>         count++;
>         j=abc.length();
>       }
>   return count;
> }
> ```

```
int letters_counted_in_text(std::wstring const&text)
{
    int count = 0;
    wstring abc = L"abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzáéíóúABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ";

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < abc.length(); ++j)
            if (text.at(i) == abc.at(j))
            {
                count++;
                j = abc.length();
            }
    return count;
}
```

**cambios:**

- `std::string const&text` por `std::wstring const&text`

.

```
int letters_counted_in_text(std::wstring const&text)
```

- `string` por [`wstring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/) y añadimos `L`:

.

```
wstring abc = L"abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzáéíóúABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ";
```

---

Comment: Muchas gracias @AngelAngel. Funcionan... la verdad pensé que se podía usar pero no sabía cómo usarlo. Como soy medio novato con C++... Gracias. Creo que puedo dar cómo solucionado o respondido la pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Una manera eficiente de hacerlo para que es esta:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::cout << "Cantidad de letras: " << converter.from_bytes( "¿Hola, cómo estás?" ).length() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Cuenta los caracteres, genial... Pero de qué forma es que este código contaría *letras*, ignorando los símbolos?

Comment: No ignora símbolos, pero es muy eficiente. Para ignorar símbolos se podría hacer como en otras respuestas: justo a continuación de este código, guarda en un wstring los caracteres que quieras ignorar y usa std::set_difference para eliminarlos.

Answer (score 0):

creo que este codigo mas o menos es lo que busca, cuenta los carateres si estos estan en el diccionario:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int contar(string str, string diccionario)
{
    int a, b, contador;
    char letra;

    contador = 0;

    int n = str.length();

    for (a = 0; a < n; a++){
        for (b = 0; b < diccionario.length(); b++){
            if (str.at(a) == diccionario.at(b))
            {   
                contador++;
                b = diccionario.length()+1;

            } 
        }
    }
    return contador;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    string test = "Hola cómo estás";//10

    string diccionario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzHóá";//Aqui los caracteres que quiere adminitir


    std::cout << "numero de letras " << contar(test, diccionario);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Le dejo estos codigos porque no tenia muy claro lo que preguntaba, *(seguramente fui yo al leer, que me costo entender lo que queria)*

con este codigo puede contar las veces que aparece un caracter siempre que este este en el diccionario.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void contar(string str, string diccionario, int i)
{
    int j, num,contador;
    char letra;

    contador = 0;

    n = str.length();

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (str.at(j) == diccionario.at(i))
        {
                contador+=1;
                letra = diccionario.at(i);
        }


    }
    //esto te muestra el numero de veces que aparece una letra
    if (contador != 0){
        std::cout << "el numero de veces de la letra " << letra << " son "<< contador << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    string test = "¿Hola, cómo estás?";

    string diccionario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzHómoestá";//Aqui los caracteres que quiere adminitir

    int i, caracteres;

    for  (i = 0; i < diccionario.length(); i++){
        contar(test, diccionario, i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

con este codigo puede contar la cantidad de caracteres diferentes, siempre que estos esten en el diccionario.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int contarDiferentes(string str, string diccionario)
{
    int a, b, contadorNoIguales;
    char letra;

    contadorNoIguales = 0;

    int n = str.length();

    for (a = 0; a < n; a++){
        for (b = 0; b < diccionario.length(); b++){
            if (str.at(a) == diccionario.at(b))
            {   
                contadorNoIguales++;
                diccionario.erase(b,1);
                b = diccionario.length()+1;

            } 
        }
    }
    return contadorNoIguales;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    string test = "Hola cómo está";

    string diccionario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzHóá";//Aqui los caracteres que quiere admitir


    std::cout << "numero de letras diferente " << contarDiferentes(test, diccionario);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Es mas que probable que los codigos anteriores se puedan optimizar pero creo que asi entendera mejor lo que hacen.

> Esto fue lo primero que le deje, pero despues me di cuenta de que no lei
>   bien la pregunta, y puse lo anterior, se le dejo por si le sirve de
>   algo como aun no me ha comentado nada en el comentario que le deje, 
>   supongo que no ha visto la respuesta:

Usted puede tratar algo similar si quiere contar los caracteres:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    string test = "¿Hola, cómo estás?";

    int spaces(0);

    for( unsigned int a( 0 ); a < test.length(); a++ ){
        if( test.at(a) == ' '){
            spaces++;
        }
    }

    int caracteres = (test.length() - spaces);

    cout << "numero de caracteres:  " << caracteres;

    return 0;
}
```

el `if` dentro del `for` se encarga de contar cuantos espacios existen dentro de la cadena para despues restarlos a la longitud del string.

---

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/

Comment: Gracias por compartir tus ideas @AngelAngel =) **letras con tilde** _me expresé mal_ en realidad son las vocales con tilde y sus mayúsculas. La idea es contar las letras de una frase u oración, cómo en el ejemplo que escribí. Estoy buscando una solución con regex del estándar

Comment: @EmanuelGauler publique una respuesta en base a su ultima edicion, tambien queria aclararle que los codigos de esta respuesta, funcionan en cuanto a que devuelven el numero correcto en su caso 13, *pero* me di cuenta que tendria que haber usado wstring por ejemplo, pero no lo use, si se prenguta por que, es que hice los codigos en un editor online y en ese si funcionaban, pero despues de su edicion lo mire en otro y no funcionaba, he preguntado el por que de ese comportamiento ...

Comment: ...y aun no he obtenido nada concluyente, ademas tambien fue sumado a que el lenguaje que estoy usando ultimante los caracteres son de 4 byte asi que entre que me parecion natural que compilara y que el compilador no se quejo lo publique asi, solo queria aclararselo. Saludos