# ¿Porqué cout no muestra vocales con tilde ni "ñ" con gcc 4.9.4?

Tags: c++, c++11

No tengo idea de porqué pasa esto. Siempre que procese los caracteres de un `string`, y este `string` tenga vocales con tilde o `ñ` los transforma y no muestra adecuadamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta (inglés)](https://superuser.com/a/394629) te ayude.

Comment: @NaCl gracias por comentar... Pero el konsole lo tengo configurado a UTF-8 y los pasos que describe son incompatibles con Kubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no se si usted soluciono este tema pero como veo comentarios de este tipo:

*usé el std::locale de gnu++11, luego cout.imbue( locale( "" ); igual me muestra incorrectamente los caracteres...*

---

Puede hacer uso de lo siguiente para mostrarlo como desea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    wcout.imbue(locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    for (auto const&t : wstring (L"áéíóú")){
        wcout << t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[testIdeone](https://ideone.com/8F2L3y)</kbd>

---

Info:

[`wstring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/)

```
wstring (L"áéíóú")
```

[`wcout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/wcout/)

```
wcout << t;
```

[`sync_with_stdio`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/)

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Comment: Gracias @AngelAngel por compartir esta solución... Probé tu solución y con el locale de mi sistema, "es_AR.UTF-8", también funcionó. Sin el locale no muestra los las vocales acentuadas. Gracias, por el momento esta solución me sirve.

Answer (score 5):

Esto se debe a la configuración regional conque se esta ejecutando tu programa; un ejemplo para localizar sería:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");


int main()
{
  cout << "áéíóú\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver mas información de esto en:

[Funciones de localización en C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_localization_functions)

Comment: Gracias por responde. Pero de esa manera muestra correctamente. El problema viene cuando proceso por caracteres...

Comment: usé el std::locale de gnu++11, luego `cout.imbue( locale( "" );` igual me muestra incorrectamente los caracteres...

Comment: Para los que vean esta respuesta, en lugar de `setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES")`, debería ser `setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish")`.

Answer (score 5):

Para que se entienda rápido:

```
std::string( "ab" ).size( ); => 2;

std::string( "ññ" ).size( ); => 4;
```

**No puedes mostrar caracteres UTF-8 como si fueran bytes ascii**.

La única solución que tienes es comprobar, 1 a 1, que los caracteres sean válidos en ASCII (7 bits). Si algún caracter no cumple esa regla, tendrías que mostrar **mas de 1 byte**.

Todos los caracteres UTF-8 tienen el bit 8 puesto a 1, con lo que la comprobación es simple:

```
if( character & 128 ) {
```

Si te encuentras con algún caracter que cumpla lo anterior, **estás ante UTF-8**.

Ante caracteres de este tipo, tienes que usar alguna librería para *extraerlo* y convertirlo en una cadena, para mostrar esta última.

Piensa que puedes encontrarte mas de un UTF-8 *seguido*, con lo que **no puedes** tomar la vía fácil de añadir caracteres a una cadena auxiliar mientras que la comprobación se cumpla. También puedes encontrarte con *secuencias* UTF-8 inválidas.

Creo que Windows provee funciones para estas cosas. En Linux, puedes usar [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)

**EDITO**

Nunca tuve la necesidad de extraer *caracteres* individuales de una `::std::string` ... hasta leer esta pregunta ;-)

Después de alguna que otra *[molestia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56542/19610)* inesperada, hice esta `template< >` que permite **iterar** sobre los caracteres individuales de cadenas UTF-8, tanto si están en un `const char *VAR="..."`, como si están en una `::std::string( "..." )`. No es lo mas *cachi piruli* del mundo, pero *ilustra* el proceso de comprobar si un carácter es o no UTF-8, y como tratarlos dependiendo de la anchura del mismo. **No** tiene en cuenta posibles errores en la codificación UTF-8, es solamente a título formativo:

```
// utf8iterator.hpp

#ifndef UTF8ITERATOR_HPP
#define UTF8ITERATOR_HPP

#include <cstddef>

template< typename T > struct utf8iterator {    
  T ptr;
  ::size_t size;
  char bytes[5];

  utf8iterator( const T &p ) :
    ptr( p ),
    size( 0 )
  {
    bytes[4] = 0;
  }
  utf8iterator &operator=( const T &iter ) {
    ptr = iter;
    size = 0;
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator==( const utf8iterator< T > &other ) const noexcept { return ptr == other.ptr; }
  bool operator!=( const utf8iterator< T > &other ) const noexcept { return ptr != other.ptr; }

  ::size_t calculateSize( ) const {
    if( ( *ptr & 248 ) == 240 ) {
      return 4;
    } else if( ( *ptr & 240 ) == 224 ) {
      return 3;
    } else if( ( *ptr & 224 ) == 192 )
      return 2;

    return 1;
  }
  utf8iterator &operator++( ) {
    if( size ) {
      ptr += size;
      size = 0;
    } else
      ptr += calculateSize( );

    return *this;
  }
  utf8iterator operator++( int ) {
    utf8iterator tmp( *this );

    if( size ) {
      ptr += size;
      size = 0;
    } else
      ptr += calculateSize( );

    return tmp;
  }
  void update( ) {
    ::size_t c;
    T iter( ptr );

    size = calculateSize( );

    for( c = 0; c != size; ++c ) {
      bytes[c] = *iter;
      ++iter;
    }

    if( size != 4 )
      bytes[size] = 0;
  }
  operator const char *( ) {
    if( !size )
      update( );

    return bytes;
  }
};

#endif
```

Un pequeño programa de prueba/ejemplo, que muestra su uso:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "utf8iterator.hpp"

int main( void ) {
  const char *test = "abcdeññ";
  std::string str( test );

  utf8iterator< const char * > charIter( test );
  utf8iterator< std::string::iterator > strIter( str.begin( ) );

  while( *charIter ) {
    std::cout << charIter << ": ";
    std::cout << charIter.size << "\n";
    ++charIter;
  }

  while( strIter != str.end( ) ) {
    std::cout << strIter << ": ";
    std::cout << strIter.size << "\n";
    ++strIter;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Tras compilarlo con `g++ -I . -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp`, muestra el siguiente resultado:

> a: 1
>   b: 1
>   c: 1
>   d: 1
>   e: 1
>   ñ: 2
>   ñ: 2
>   a: 1
>   b: 1
>   c: 1
>   d: 1
>   e: 1
>   ñ: 2
>   ñ: 2

Muestra adecuadamente los caracteres individuales, tanto en `char *` como en `std::string`, ocupen los *bytes* que ocupen.

Comment: Gracias @Trauma por explicarme. Es lo que veía cuando pasaba un carácter a cout, siempre mostraba dos íconos con signo de interrogación. Me parece raro que std++11 no pueda manejar esta situación. Siendo que también está el std::locale. Y el locale de mi sistema es "es_AR.UTF-8"

Comment: Está bueno el código fuente de tu _utf8iterator_ @Trauma podrías agregar cómo respuesta a esta pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55302/32772

Answer (score 1):

Puedes iterar sobre los "bytes" de una cadena en que esta en UTF-8 y sacar esos bytes por otro lado.

Lo que no puedes hacer nunca es "intercalar" caracteres/bytes (en este caso fin de linea: el "endl") entre esos bytes que estas iterando, ya que hay caracteres que son formados por dos bytes (la ñ, la á, etc) y no son "separables".

Para entender mejor lo que digo arriba, este codigo funciona solo para caracteres (unicode) menores que 0x800 (menores que 8*256, la 'ñ', 'á', son menores que 1*256):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for (auto const&l : string("áaéeiíóúñ")) {
    cout << l;
    if ((l&0xc0)!=0xc0)
      cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Salida:

```
á
a
é
e
i
í
ó
ú
ñ
```

He intercalado retornos de linea solo en "algunos casos" entre los "bytes" de salida.

Comment: Gracias @AngelMoreno por tu explicación