# Duda con listas ligadas (punteros) C++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

El ejercicio en cuestión es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo ya este código en el header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H7

//Tipo dato Nodo
struct Nodo
{
    int dato;
    Nodo* izq;
    Nodo* der;
};

//Tipo dato Estructura
struct Estructura
{
   Nodo* inicio;
   Nodo* fin;
};


void inicializarEstructura(Estructura& est);
//{PRE: 'est.inicio' es nullptr y ‘est.fin’ es nullptr}

#endif // HEADER_H
```

Y este es el código que tengo de momento del main:

```
//Tema 1. Ejercicios punteros.

#include <iostream>
#include <header.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    return 0;
}

void inicializarEstructura(Estructura& est)
{
     //1º Aquí asigno memoria dinámica para cada nodo
     Nodo* p = new Nodo;
     Nodo* q = new Nodo;
     Nodo* h = new Nodo;

     //2º Asigno los punteros correspondientes
     //2.1º Primero los punteros de la Estructura "est" a nodo
     *est.inicio = *q->der;
     *est.fin = *h->izq;
     //2.2º Segundo los punteros de nodo a nodo
     *q->der = *est.fin;
     *p->izq = *est.inicio;
     est.fin->izq = p->dato;
}
```

Me salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sólo me da el error cuando intento apuntar con la variable izq(de tipo nodo) del tercer nodo, a la variable dato(de tipo int) del 1er nodo.

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Gracias de antemano.

PD: Recibir una respuesta me es importante, necesito entender el concepto de puntero correctamente, y creo que al ver este ejercicio resuelto entenderé bastante mejor este tema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
est.fin->izq = p->dato;
```

Si `dato` es un entero, **no** puedes asignarlo a un puntero.

Lo que quieres hacer, inicializar la lista, es muy simple

```
void inicializarEstructura( Estructura& est ) {
  nodo *izquierda = new Nodo;
  nodo *centro = new Nodo;
  nodo *derecha = new Nodo;

  izquierda->izq = nullptr;
  izquierda->dato = 2;
  izquierda->der = centro;

  centro->izq = izquierda;
  centro->dato = 1;
  dentro->der = nullptr;

  derecha->izq = centro;
  derecha->dato = 3;
  derecha->der = nullptr;

  est.inicio = izquierda;
  est.fin = derecha.
}
```

[Preguntas sobre *punteros*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/punteros) hay unas cuantas en el sitio. Puedes consultarlas, para ver ejemplos varios y variados.

Comment: Gracias por responder, al ver tu respuesta creo que mi lectura del ejercicio era incorrecta, por eso me estaba liando tanto. Creía que determinadas partes del nodo apuntaban a determinadas partes de otro nodo y no al nodo en conjunto.El ejercicio ahora me parece realmente sencillo.

Comment: @AguaMineral tienes razón; **no** es una lista enlazada real, es parecida, pero no lo es. Edito la respuesta. Al igual que te pasó a ti, no miré bien el ejercicio.

Comment: No hay problema, muchas gracias por corregirlo.

Comment: "*Si `dato` es un entero, **no** puedes asignarlo a un puntero*". De hecho si puedes, y es un serio problema en C y C++ :O

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no me seas *puntilloso*; si puedes, pero no así, a lo bruto; el compilador se queja con `invalid conversion from int to Nodo*`.

Comment: @Trauma No soy puntilloso... no se queja en caso de `Nodo *a = NULL` siendo `NULL` un entero (`#define NULL 0`) ;P

Comment: No, no eres *puntilloso*; que va . Venga, va, monta una respuesta para explicar eso, y le añades el `nullptr`

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Espera, que lo pongo como pregunta aparte.

Comment: @Trauma Los programadores tenemos la responsabilidad de ser puntillosos. Una coma, una letra, un número o una expresión mal puesta suponen que todo deje de funcionar... ¡la programación es una ciencia exacta! >:(

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster que me lo digan [a mi:](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56542/19610). Mas de 1 hora, por culpa de un `*` mal puesto :-(. Estoy montando una pregunta, ahora te aviso.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ale, pregunta [publicada:](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56749/19610).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster `Los programadores tenemos la responsabilidad de ser puntillosos` ... jeje ... yo no soy programador 

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando los puntos (.) que aparecen en los errores por flecha (->)

> Para tener acceso a los miembros de una estructura, utilice el operador punto. Para tener acceso a los miembros de una estructura a través de un puntero, utilice el operador flecha.

[Operador flecha](http://www.w3ii.com/es/cplusplus/cpp_member_operators.html)

[Arrows pagina en ingles](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/53293/)

[Operadores de punteros en español](http://www.zator.com/Cpp/E4_9_11.htm)

Comment: Ya lo corregí, pero en uno de los punteros sigue dándome un error que no se cómo solucionar, he editado la pregunta desde el código main.

Comment: Me parece que estas interpretando mal tu diagrama, para mi que la flecha en el diagrama apunta a la estructura no al valor dentro de ella. Si te fijas cuando se refiere a un valor interno la flecha atraviesa los rectángulos. Pero bueno ya dependería de la explicación que te dieron al dejarte el ejercicio o a lo que viste en clase.

Comment: Estabas en lo correcto, mi interpretación del ejercicio era errónea.