# Duda con enteros, punteros, y nullptr

Tags: c++, punteros

Una duda que me ha surgido; si hago

```
struct Lista {
  struct Lista *inicio;
  struct Lista *fin;
};

int main( void ) {
  Lista *l1 = new Lista;

  l1->inicio = 0; // Ok.
  l1->inicio = 100; // Error.
  l1->inicio = nullptr; // Ok.

  return 0;
}
```

Al compilarlo con `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic`, arroja el siguiente error:

> `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Lista*’: l1->inicio = 100;`

¿ Como es esto ? ¿ Porqué puedo asignarle un `0`, pero no otro número ?

¿ Y que es `nullptr` ?

***Nada, que no me aclaro***

```
l1->fin = new Lista; // Ok.
l1->fin = reinterpret_cast< Lista * >( 100 ); // ¡¡ funciona !!
l1->fin = (Lista *)100; // ¡¡ también funciona !!
```

¿ Pero entonces, **que demonios es un puntero** ?

Comment: Hombre te recomiendo que aprendas para que se utilizan los punteros, lo que tu haces allí no tiene sentido alguno, un puntero es usado para referencias, en la mayor parte para manejar el mismo tipo de dato, si creas un puntero apuntando a `Lista`, tienes que almacenar el puntero de otra instancia a `Lista`, cada puntero es una dirección en la memoria, tu allí estas intentando almacenar 100 en una dirección que no existe.

Comment: @nikomaster Gracias por tu interés. Ciertamente, aún tengo que aprender mucho sobre [*punteros*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/punteros/topusers) ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`nullptr` es una palabra reservada que aparece en C++11 y viene a ser un sustituto natural de `NULL`. Su utilidad es eliminar ambigüedades al trabajar con punteros, como se puede observar en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
void func(int*);
void func(int);

int* ptr;
func(ptr);     // Llama a func(int*);
func(0);       // Llama a func(int);
func(NULL);    // Llama a func(int);
func(nullptr); // Llama a func(int*);
```

Por otro lado, al compilar tu ejemplo:

```
l1->inicio = 0; // Ok.
l1->inicio = 100; // Error.
```

Tenemos lo siguiente:

- `ptr=0`. Esta sentencia es legal porque es la inicialización clásica de un puntero. Los punteros únicamente deberían apuntar a una posición de memoria válida o a la posición 0. Es debido a esta segunda posibilidad que la línea es aceptada por el compilador. Lo correcto a partir de C++11 sería `ptr = nullptr`.
- `ptr=100`: Esta sentencia no es válida porque es **imposible** que una reserva facilitada por el Sistema Operativo coincida con el valor `100` (sustituye ese valor por cualquier otro valor fijo). En consecuencia el compilador entiende que la inicialización del puntero no es válida y te arroja el correspondiente error.

---

**edito**

Seguimos resolviendo dudas:

- `reinterpret_cast` viene a ser la traducción de... "*voy a hacer algo que normalmente no debería y que asumo que es peligroso, pero engaño al compilador para que confíe en mi y me deje trabajar*". Es decir, en ese caso le estás diciendo al compilador que eres consciente de que la conversión no es segura pero que aún así sabes lo que haces y eso desactiva el error en tiempo de compilación.
- `(int*)100` es una conversión clásica heredada de C. La lógica detrás de esta conversión es la misma que la comentada con `reinterpret_cast`. La gran diferencia entre ambas opciones es que esta debería ser evitada ya que es más complicada de localizar en el código.

> ¿Pero entonces, que demonios es un puntero?

Un puntero no es más que una variable, lo que sucede es que en vez de almacenar valores hace lo propio con direcciones de memoria. En lo tocante a la pregunta, el compilador de C++ verifica que el uso que se hace del puntero sea (o aparente ser) el correcto.

El compilador acepta que un puntero apunte a una variable cualquiera del programa aunque la misma pueda dejar de estar "*viva*" en cualquier momento (tener en cuenta esto último es responsabilidad del programador), pero no acepta que el puntero apunte a direcciones de memoria concretas ya que eso es sinónimo de error el 100% de las veces salvo que estemos hablando de sistemas embebidos, donde la situación puede cambiar.

¿Y por qué acceder a una posición fija de memoria suele estar mal?

Básicamente porque los Sistemas Operativos actuales son sumamente complejos además implementan (apoyados por la infraestructura hardware) numerosos chequeos para controlar el acceso a los diferentes recursos del sistema. Estos chequeos son los responsables de que una aplicación *se muera* al intentar escribir en zonas de memoria que no le pertenecen (es una manera de evitar que un proceso con errores corrompa la memoria de otros procesos).

Intentar acceder a una posición fija de memoria implica que la inmensa mayoría de las veces el puntero acabará direccionando una posición de memoria que no pertenece a tu proceso y a la que, por tanto, no tendrás acceso.

Comment: Pregunta editada. Aquí puedes *explayarte*, eferion. ¡ Que se note el *power* de los *respondedores* de C++ !

Answer (score 4):

Ante dudas de este tipo, no tenemos más que consultar <strike>La Biblia</strike> el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf). En concreto el apartado sobre conversiones de punteros indica... (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 4.10 Conversiones de punteros
>
> **Una *constante de puntero nulo* es un literal entero con valor cero** o un valor puro del lado derecho (*prvalue*) de tipo `std::nullptr_t`. Una constante de puntero nulo puede ser convertida a puntero a tipo, el resultado es el *valor de puntero nulo* de ese tipo y es distinguible de cualquier otro valor de puntero a objeto o puntero a función. [...]

Así que ante la pregunta "*¿Porqué puedo asignarle un `0`, pero no otro número?*" la respuesta acorde al estándar es que el cero (y sólo el cero) es considerado puntero, en concreto puntero nulo.

#### ¿Qué es [`nullptr`](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#nullptr)?

La palabra clave [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) representa un literal de puntero nulo (de la misma manera que el cero (`0`) representa la [identidad aditiva](http://www.mathematicsdictionary.com/spanish/vmd/full/a/additiveidentity.htm) en álgebra).

Se incorporó al lenguaje C++ en el estándar de 2011 (C++11) porque el uso de `0` como literal de puntero nulo provocaba ciertas ambigüedades que daban lugar a errores difíciles de detectar, por ejemplo:

```
void funcion(int valor)    { ... }
void funcion(int *puntero) { ... }

funcion(0);
```

¿Qué sobrecarga de `funcion` tiene que llamar la instrucción `funcion(0)`? *Sorprendentemente* escoge la sobrecarga de entero... aunque no es tan sorprendente pues `0` es un entero ¿verdad? Oh, pero también es el literal de puntero nulo; así que si queríamos llamar a la sobrecarga con puntero debemos trampear la llamada:

```
funcion(static_cast<int *>(0));
```

Lo cuál es bastante incómodo, pero usando `nullptr`:

```
funcion(nullptr);
```

Se hace la llamada a la sobrecarga con puntero. Semánticamente es inambiguo y denota una clara intencionalidad de usar punteros al contrario que usando `0` que en ciertos contextos no se sabe si se trata de un entero o un puntero.

---

Respecto a forzar conversiones a puntero...

> ```
> l1->fin = new Lista; // Ok.
> l1->fin = reinterpret_cast< Lista * >( 100 ); // ¡¡ funciona !!
> l1->fin = (Lista *)100; // ¡¡ también funciona !!
> ```

... entramos en terreno pantanoso. Tal vez te sorprenda que aplicar conversión de estilo C o la conversión estilo C++ sobre un entero a puntero funcione, pero en realidad no es más sorprendente que los mismos tipos de conversión aplicada en otros tipos incompatibles:

```
Patata p;
Lista *l = reinterpret_cast< Lista *>( &p );
Lista *m = (Lista *)&p;
Lista *n = (Lista *)"En un lugar de La Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no hace mucho tiempo atrás que un hidalgo cabalgaba.";
const Lista *o = reinterpret_cast< const Lista *>("De los de lanza en ristre, rocín flaco, y galgo corredor.");
```

Las conversiones estilo C++ son más restrictivas que las de estilo C por eso `reinterpret_cast` sobre un puntero constante requiere que el puntero de destino también lo sea (y la conversión estilo C no lo requiere).

En este caso, la sección relevante del [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) es la referente a `reinterpret_cast` (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.2.10 Conversiones de reinterpretación
>
> 1. **El resultado de la expresión `reinterpret_cast<T>(v)` es el resultado de convertir la expresión `v` al tipo `T`**. Si `T` es una referencia a valor de lado izquierdo o una referencia a valor de lado derecho a un tipo de función, el resultado es una referencia a valor de lado izquierdo; si `T` es una referencia a valor de lado derecho a un tipo de objeto, el resultado es un valor expirante; en otro caso, el resultado es un valor puro de lado derecho y se aplican a la expresión `v` las conversiones estándar de valor-izquierdo-a-valor-derecho, arreglo-a-puntero y función-a-puntero. **Las conversiones que pueden ser realizadas explícitamente usando `reinterpret_cast` se listan a continuación. Ninguna otra conversión puede ser realizada explícitamente usando `reinterpret_cast`**.
> 2. **`reinterpret_cast` no debe eliminar la constancia de datos**. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> 7. **Un puntero a objeto puede ser convertido a puntero a objeto de tipo diferente**. [...]

Así pues, el estándar de C++ establece que `reinterpret_cast` puede convertir punteros de un tipo a punteros de otro tipo.

Respecto a la conversión de tipo C la del [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) es (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.5 Conversión explícita de tipos (notación de conversión)
>
> 1. El resultado de la expresión `(T)` *expresión-a-convertir* es el tipo `T`. [...] [*Nota:* **Si `T` es un tipo no-clase que está cualificado como constante o volátil, los *cualificadores-cv* se descartan** cuando se determina el tipo del valor puro del lado derecho; —*fin de la nota* ]

#### ¿Qué demonios es un puntero?

Podemos ver que según el estándar de C++ un puntero es una categoría de tipo especial sobre la que se pueden aplicar ciertas conversiones que no serían posibles en otra categoría de tipos.

A nivel menos técnico, un puntero es una variable numérica que identifica una dirección de memoria en la que estarán contenidos los datos binarios de otro dato; las conversiones de reinterpretación simplemente indican la manera en que deben interpretarse los datos binarios apuntados... como analogía diríamos que te doy la dirección de la oficina de correos más cercana pero te envío a una biblioteca: he reinterpretado la dirección de la biblioteca como la dirección de correos... seguramente no puedas enviar cartas desde la biblioteca ¡pero nada te impide intentarlo!.

Comment: Edité la pregunta con mas *dudillas* que *me pueden llegar a surgir* en un momento dado ... ¡ a ver ese *power* del C++ !