# ¿Cómo imprimir caracteres con acentos en c++?

Tags: c++

Por ejemplo si uso:

```
printf("ó á");
```

El resultado obtenido en la consola es:

```
¾ ß
```

Dónde **3/4** representa **ó** y **ß** representa a la **á**

Comment: aqui tienes varias respuestas quizas es lo que buscas https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56038/porqu%C3%A9-cout-no-muestra-vocales-con-tilde-ni-%C3%B1-con-gcc-4-9-4/ Saludos

Comment: eso es C y no C++ , porque usan printf?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    printf("ó á");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Lo que hacemos es incluir las librerias `wchar.h`, que incluye un soporte para amplios tipos de caracteres y la libreria `locale.h` con la que se incluye el soporte para distintos tipos de formatos de fecha, moneda, texto, etc.

Solo basta usar la funcion:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

La que nos permitira usar en nuestro programa distintos tipos de caracteres que no pertenezcan al "estandar", que se puede imprimir normalmente.

**Resultado:**

> ó á
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.038 s
>
> Press any key to continue.

Comment: Eso no es correcto. Se imprime bien sin establecer el locale: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw45LXx8hWJ6ckViELpiTn5yYkwoSRdGdk5kEEuPKzCtRyE3MzNMoy89M0azmAupVAILi1BKIRg0f53hHHx8dBSUlTWsuLpBcQRFQU5qG0uHNCocXwkWLUktKi/IUXCM8Q@KDQ52dXYODrblq//8HAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Agradezco el comentario, aunque ya no soy usuario activo de esta comunidad, siempre es bueno aprender, gracias

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Hace tres años al usuario no le imprimía, en su momento supongo que ahora algo habra cambiado, en fin, gracias por el ejemplo, saludos!

Comment: Yo no respondo la pregunta porque no conozco la respuesta, pero las pruebas que hago me indican que tu respuesta tampoco responde correctamente a la pregunta.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Bueno, han pasado 3 años, de hecho fue cerca a mi cumpleaños, en ese momento, entonces, fallaba, en fin, borrar la respuesta no puedo. Saludos!

Answer (score 9):

Podrías probar invocando los caracteres

```
printf("%c Ponemos el acento o tilde en canel%cn\n",162, 162); //ó
```

Es decir, invocar el código de carácter que corresponde a la letra acentuada...

Códigos:

á: 160
é: 130
í: 161
ó: 162
ú: 163
Á: 181
É: 144
Í: 214
Ó: 224
Ú: 223
ñ: 164
Ñ: 165

Comment: La U está mal: es 233 y no 23. Lo otro agregaría más símbolos como ¡ 173 o ¿ 168

Answer (score 8):

Tienes que tener la codificación de carácteres de la terminal, igual que la codificación de cáracteres de tu fichero de texto. Si tu fichero de texto está en UTF-8, la terminal debe estar en UTF-8. Si está en UCS-16, pues igual, la terminal en UCS-16, etc...

El compilador, que no tiene en cuenta la codificación del fichero fuente, toma los literales de cadena tal cual, y los guarda en la memoria del ejecutable. Y cuando los imprimes, se volcarán, tal cual estaba escrito, en la terminal. Si la codificación de la terminal es diferente a la del fichero, interpretará la secuencia binaria de la cadena como carácteres diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

El caracter á es este numero hexadecimal, dependiendo de la codificación:

```
UNICODE:                 E1
iso-8859-1:              E1
Cp1252 (Windows):        E1
Codepage 850 de MS-DOS:  A0
UTF-8:                   C3 A1 (dos bytes)
EBCDIC (IBM Mainframes): 45
```

Si a un terminal MSDOS con codepage 850 (el España), le llega el byte E1, este pintara un:
ß

Si estamos en MSDOS 850, habria que lanzar un byte A0 para que saliese 'á'.

De todas es mejor lanzar bytes iso que bytes codepage-850 ya en desuso.

De hecho en linux el UTF-8 es el más standard.

http://www.vicente-navarro.com/blog/2008/06/15/juegos-de-caracteres-ascii-cp850-iso-8859-15-unicode-utf-8/

Answer (score 2):

Debes utiizar los equivalentes:

```
á –> \xA0; 
é –> \x82; 
í –> \xA1; 
ó –> \xA2; 
ú –> \xA3; 
ñ –> \xA4; 
Ñ –> \xA5;
á -> 160; 
é -> 130; 
í -> 161; 
ó -> 162; 
ú -> 163; 
ñ -> 164;
```

Por ejemplo:

`Canción` >> `Canci\xA2n`

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn por favor agrega una explicaciòn de lo que realiza el còdigo, revisa [answer], saludos.

Comment: listado completo á –> \xA0
é –> \x82
í –> \xA1
ó –> \xA2
ú –> \xA3
Á -> \xB5
É -> \x90
Í -> \xD6
Ó -> \xE0
Ú -> \xE9
ñ –> \xA4
Ñ –> \xA5
¿ -> \A8
¡ -> \AD

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera de imprimir caracteres especiales en Windows es con las funciones [Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api) del sistema. En particular, las que tienen una W al final, como [`WriteConsoleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole).

Un pequeño detalle a tener en cuenta, estas funciones utilizan caracteres de tipo `wchar_t`, o [`WCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/wchar).

Con un código tan simple como este, es posible imprimir caracteres especiales:

```
WCHAR cadena[] = L"ó á";
WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cadena, 3, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Brevemente, `WriteConsole` recibe:

Un `HANDLE` al buffer de salida de la consola, la cadena y la cantidad de caracteres a imprimir. Opcionalmente un puntero a un `DWORD`, que contendrá la cantidad de caracteres escritos. Y un parámetro reservado que debe ser **NULL** (o `nullptr` o 0).

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que la manera más fácil de imprimir estos caracteres es utilizar la librería declarandola en la cima como "#include" y a continuación escribimos "" que contiene la función "setlocale (LC_CTYPE, "Spanish")" , al escribir esa función justo después de declarar las variables ya tomará caracteres con tildes e incluso la letra 'ñ'

Answer (score 0):

Solo es implementar una librería.

```
#include<locale.h>
```

Y colocar dentro del main un:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
```

Esto hará que cualquier texto que coloques en un cout pueda leer un (ñ, ó, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Te traigo la solución.

Lo bajo de una forma simple mediante este código:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <locale.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {

        // Para Linux - Usa locale.h
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish");

        // Para Windows - Usa Windows.h
        SetConsoleCP(1252);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);

        return 0;

    }
```

Esta función la podés llamar después donde quieras.

¡Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Pero cuando se guarda un nombre, por ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream> // Permite el flujo de entrada y salidad de datos.
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std; // Permite el uso de espacios de nombres std.

int main(){ // Inicio de la función principal.

    setlocale( LC_ALL, "spanish" ); // Permite el uso de caracteres del español.

    // Declaración de variables.
    string nombre;

    cout << "¿Cómo te llamas?";
    cin >> nombre;

    cout << "Mucho gusto " << nombre;

    return 0; // Finaliza el programa con éxito.
} // Fin de la función principal.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Julio, bienvenido, no me queda claro cual es tu intención, pareciera que quieres hacer una pregunta, si es así, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes 

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.