# Como poner acentos en C++

Tags: c++

estoy usando code::blocks en macOS BigSur, he intentado poner el acento en código ASCII pero en la terminal me aparece: "Programaci?n".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Programaci\242n" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo imprimir caracteres con acentos en c++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/c%c3%b3mo-imprimir-caracteres-con-acentos-en-c)

Comment: créeme que lo intente, pero funciona en windows

Comment: No me queda clara tu pregunta. El código `242` (`F2` hex) **no es válido** en UTF-8. Por tanto, ¿ Que es lo que quieres hacer ? ¿ Convertir ese código en su equivalente UTF-8 ?