# Usar caracteres ascii c++

Tags: c++, ascii

Estoy intentando escribir en la consola caracteres raros para una cosa.
digamos que quiero poner este mensaje:

```
                    ██████████                                      
                   ░░███░░░░███                                     
                    ░███   ░░███ ████████   ██████   █████ ███ █████
                    ░███    ░███░░███░░███ ░░░░░███ ░░███ ░███░░███ 
                    ░███    ░███ ░███ ░░░   ███████  ░███ ░███ ░███ 
                    ░███    ███  ░███      ███░░███  ░░███████████  
                    ██████████   █████    ░░████████  ░░████░████   
                   ░░░░░░░░░░   ░░░░░      ░░░░░░░░    ░░░░ ░░░░
```

pues despues de compilar y ejecutar obtengo este mensaje:

```
ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê
                       ÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê
                        ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê   ÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê   ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê   ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê
                        ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê    ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê
                        ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê    ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûæÔûæÔûæ   ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê  ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê
                        ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê    ÔûêÔûêÔûê  ÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê      ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûê  ÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê
                        ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê   ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê    ÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê  ÔûæÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûæÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê
                       ÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæ   ÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæ      ÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæ    ÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæ ÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæ
```

Lo estoy intentando asi:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string test = " ██████████                                      \n"
                       "░░███░░░░███                                     \n"
                       " ░███   ░░███ ████████   ██████   █████ ███ █████\n"
                       " ░███    ░███░░███░░███ ░░░░░███ ░░███ ░███░░███ \n"
                       " ░███    ░███ ░███ ░░░   ███████  ░███ ░███ ░███ \n"
                       " ░███    ███  ░███      ███░░███  ░░███████████  \n"
                       " ██████████   █████    ░░████████  ░░████░████   \n"
                       "░░░░░░░░░░   ░░░░░      ░░░░░░░░    ░░░░ ░░░░    \n";
    std::cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suena a que la consola que estás usando está en Unicode y lee tus carácteres de otra forma. Busca tablas ASCII extendidas y revisa.

Comment: ¿Qué compilador y sistema operativo estás usando? ¿Esto responde a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59791/169744

Comment: Estoy utilizando windows y compilo con g++