# Por qué no puedo imprimir estos caracteres en la consola? (CLion)

Tags: c++

Uso CLion IDE.  Estoy haciendo un buscaminas jugable a través de la consola.  Tengo las bibliotecas GTest para los test suites.  Cuando trato de imprimir estos caracteres usando el ejecutable GTest, se imprimen bien, pero cuando no quiero ejecutar las pruebas, se imprimen estos códigos aleatorios.  ¿Como puedo resolver esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo estás usando? En Linux no deberías tener ese problema ya que la consola por defecto usa codificación UTF-8. Mira [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59791/169744), es posible que encuentres la solución ahí.

Comment: Uso Windows, supuestamente mi IDE ya usa UTF-8. Por otro lado, la solucion de la otra pregunta no me ayudo. Intente incluyendo:
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
y setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); en el main y funciones que realizan el cout<<
pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: No tengo CLion así que no puedo saber exactamente la causa. Pero, ¿qué compilador usas? A lo mejor la solución depende del compilador y no del IDE.

Comment: GCC 12.1.0. Busque varias soluciones pero ya no se que hacer