# C++. Leer archivo .txt y sacarlo por consola con ñ y tildes

Tags: c++, txt, stream

Estoy intentando leer un txt con ifstream y luego mostrar el texto en la consola.
Pero, no muestra bien la letra ñ y las vocales con tilde. El archivo texInput.txt está en utf-8 with BOM.

Este es el texInput.txt:

```
Esta es una de las problemáticas: " ñ ",
y estas tampoco salen bien: "á   é   í   or   ú"
```

El código main.cpp:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <locale.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    wstring inputStr;
    wchar_t wc;
    wifstream te;
    
    void openTxt();
    void readTxt();
    void closeTxt();
    void wait();
    
    int main(){
      setlocale(LC_ALL,"Spanish");
    
      openTxt();
      readTxt();
      closeTxt();
      wait();
      return 0;
    }
    
    void openTxt(){
      te.open("texInput.txt",ios::in);
      if (te.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo de texto";
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    
    void readTxt(){
      while(te.good()){
        te.get(wc);
        inputStr.push_back(wc);
        }
      wcout<<inputStr<<endl;
    }
    
    void closeTxt(){
      te.close();
    }
    
    void wait(){
      wcout<<L"type something to exit: "<<endl;
      wcin>>wc;
    }
```

la salida por consola:

```
ï»¿Esta es una de las problemÃ¡ticas: " Ã± ",
y estas tampoco salen bien: "Ã¡   Ã©   Ã­   or   Ãº"

type something to exit:
```

Este sitio me pide que añada más detalles a mi pregunta para poder publicar.
Aunque creo que la pregunta está clara, estoy escribiendo estas líneas para poder publicar la pregunta. La verdad es que no termino de entender cómo hacer para que sean compatibles las distintas codificaciones. No entiendo bien cómo es el tema y no encuentro una buena explicación en internet.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo imprimir caracteres con acentos en c++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/c%c3%b3mo-imprimir-caracteres-con-acentos-en-c)

Comment: La lectura desde archivos no suele causar problemas. Lo que sí da problemas es la codificación a la hora de mostrarlos y la codificación del código fuente.