# mi consola no muestra simbolos

Tags: c++

tengo este código

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class Cuenta { //crea la clase cuenta
public:
 int x;
 void imprime() { cout << x <<" ♥-♥-♥"<< endl; }//le asigna una funcion a "imprime"
};
int main()
{
    
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); //codigo para poder usar simbolos ♥♦♣♠
setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);
    
 Cuenta contador, //crea el objeto de la clase
 *ptrContador = &contador, //se crea un apuntador que apunta a "contador"
 &refContador = contador; //se crea una referencia de "contador"
 cout << "♥ Asigna 7 a x y lo imprime utilizando el nombre del objeto ♥: ";
 contador.x = 7; //le asigna un valor a la clase
 contador.imprime(); 
 cout << "♥ Asigna 8 a x y lo imprime utilizando una referencia ♥: ";
 refContador.x = 8; //le asigna un valor a la referencia
 refContador.imprime(); 
 cout << "♥ Asigna 10 a x y lo imprime utilizando un apuntador ♥: ";
 ptrContador->x = 10; //le asigna un valor al apuntador
 ptrContador->imprime(); 
 return 0;
}
```

al compilar me imprime los símbolos como signos de interrogación (??).
el código lo probé en una computadora de la escuela y muestra los símbolos correctamente, pero en mi computadora no, uso embarcadero dev c++ en windows 11

Comment: Es un problema conocido y ya hay otras preguntas al respecto. Por ejemplo [¿Cómo imprimir caracteres con acentos en c++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/c%c3%b3mo-imprimir-caracteres-con-acentos-en-c)

Comment: En el caso particular de Windows es complicado. Creo que no debes usar ninguna función estándar ya que no solucionan nada (como `setvbuf`). Sino que debes usar exclusivamente las funciones de Windows como `WriteConsole` y `SetConsoleOutputCP`.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo utilizar printf en vez de cout para ese caso, para esto necesitas la tabla de ASCII (que puedes encontrarla en internet), por ejemplo:

```
printf("símbolo cerrazón: %c", 03);
```

%c indica que se va a colocar un carácter de tipo char en esa posición, y luego de la coma (,) colocas el numero que indica al valor que quieres poner.
El resultado de esto es lo siguiente:

> símbolo corazón: ♥

En la siguiente imagen se puede observar que el símbolo de corazón (♥) se indica con el número 03

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un video por si te quedaste con alguna duda:
[Como poner caracteres especiales](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5E2Fy_4ThA)

Answer (score 0):

Para que los símbolos se impriman correctamente la codificación de la consola debe ser la misma que la del texto a imprimir.

Con

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

Estás haciendo que la consola imprima caracteres en UTF-8.

Así que puedes reemplazar el símbolo por sus bytes mediante una secuencia de escape.

Los bytes del [símbolo del corazón en UTF-8](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) son **0xE2 0x99 0xA5**. En secuencias de escape, lo puedes escribir así:

```
// Original
cout << "♥ Asigna 7 a x y lo imprime utilizando el nombre del objeto ♥: ";

// Modificado
cout << "\xE2\x99\xA5 Asigna 7 a x y lo imprime utilizando el nombre del objeto \xE2\x99\xA5: ";
```

En C++ también existen otros [literales para cadenas de caracteres](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), entre ellos uno para UTF-8. Solo debes agregar **u8** antes de abrir las comillas. El código se vería así:

```
cout << u8"♥ Asigna 7 a x y lo imprime utilizando el nombre del objeto ♥: ";
```