# wchar_t no imprime letras con tildes

Tags: c, unicode

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
int
wordsAnalyzer(char* dir){
    FILE* doc = fopen(dir,"r");
    wchar_t myChar;
    int count = 0;

    while((myChar = fgetwc(doc)) != EOF){
        putwchar(myChar);
    }
    getchar();

    return count;
}
```

Y trato de imprimir el siguiente texto (que esta dentro de un archivo):

> Hólà

Al imprimirlo aparece esto:

> H?l?

Por lo que entiendo `wchar.h` es la librería que me permite manejar caracteres unicode, pero hasta el momento no he podido hacerla funcionar ¿Cual es el problema?

PD: Ahora he probado agregando setlocale(LC_ALL,""); a mi código y la impresión del archivo cambia a:

> H

Comment: esta pregunta -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56038/porqu%C3%A9-cout-no-muestra-vocales-con-tilde-ni-%C3%B1-con-gcc-4-9-4 puede estar relacionada con lo que busca. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Hay varias cuestiones de las que tienes que asegurarte para que tu programa imprima Hólà :

1.- El fichero que contiene la cadena Hólà debe estar grabado con una codificación compatible con el locale con que vas a ejecutar el programa. Yo lo voy a hacer con el locale es_ES.UTF-8
Por tanto el fichero debe estar codificado en UTF-8.
Si haces un hexdump de un fichero con la cadena Hólà y nada más, ni retornos de carro ni nada, debes obtener :

```
jose@cpu:~/t$ hexdump -C fich.txt
00000000  48 c3 b3 6c c3 a0                                 |H..l..|
00000006
```

Donde :

```
48    Unicode U+0048 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H (Mayúscula latina H)
c3b3  Unicode U+00F3 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE (Minúscula latina O
                                                      con tilde cerrada)
6c    Unicode U+006C LATIN SMALL LETTER L (Minúscula latina L)
c3a0  Unicode U+00E0 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE (Minúscula latina A
                                                      con tilde abierta)
```

Puedes consultar los códigos unicode en http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

2.- Tu programa debe cargar el locale establecido en las variables de entorno. Esto lo haces bien.

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "");
```

3.- El locale ha de estar disponible en tu sistema.
Por ejemplo, en un sistema Ubuntu has de editar el fichero /etc/locale.gen
Y asegurarte de que contiene esta línea :

es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8

Si no la contenía o la contenía comentada (empezando por #) entonces has de ejecutar `locale-gen` después de editarlo.

4.- El usuario debe establecer el locale. Esto es lo que tenías mal.
Usando bash sería así:

```
jose@cpu:~/t$ LC_ALL=es_ES.utf8
jose@coy:~/t$ ./programa
Hólà
```