# Los caracteres anchos de C++ no se imprimen correctamente en la consola

Tags: c++

Este es un problema que vengo arrastrando desde que empecé a programar en c++ y se resume en que los caracteres anchos no se editan correctamente al usar un índice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


int main(){
    
    std::wstring cadena = L"Hoy es un d?a muy lindo";
    
    cadena[11]=wchar_t(L'í');
    
    std::wcout << cadena << std::endl;
    
}
```

la salida que obtengo en la consola es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que esperaba es la vocal i con tilde pero obtengo una Y con tilde que desconozco de que idioma es. No se si es la consola que no imprime correctamente los caracteres no ascii o es la codificación interna de los wstring.

Por alguna extraña razón las cadenas no ascii me funcionan fatal, nunca logro hacer nada con ellas y estoy por abandonar el lenguaje c++ ya que estoy acostumbrado al unicode utf8 de python y no encuentro una solución similar para ese tipo de codificación.

Comment: Fijate si te sirve [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56038/porqu%C3%A9-cout-no-muestra-vocales-con-tilde-ni-%C3%B1-con-gcc-4-9-4)